# Rails simple form input show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using the `ancestry gem` in order to create categories and subcategories(parent, child, sibling). Then I have a select input inside a simple form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :parent_category_id, collection: @categories, label: "Category", as: :grouped_select, group_method: :children, include_blank: true, input_html: { id: 'first-dropdown' } %>
</div>
```

I populate the above input with the parent categories:

```
@categories = Category.where(ancestry: nil)
```

And when I select a category in the above input the subcategories appear in the input below. If the category has no subcategories then the input is empty.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.input :category_id, label: "Subcategories", :collection => [], :label_method => :name, :value_method => :id, required: true, input_html: { multiple: true, id: 'second-dropdown' } %>
</div>

$('#first-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'categories/select_item?category_id=' + $(this).val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            let childElement = $('#second-dropdown');
            childElement.html('');
            data.forEach(function(v) {
                let id = v.id;
                let name = v.name;
                childElement.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works just fine with this setup. But now I would like to add a feature which I don't know how to. I want the second input to be initially hidden. And I want to show the second input if subcategories exist and hide the second input if subcategories don't exist. Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

this could work...

```
    success: function(data) {
        let childElement = $('#second-dropdown');             
        childElement.toggle(Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andre Figueiredo. The code you provided does hide and does show the input according to if subcategories are present. But it messes up the subcategories, it adds the new ones from the selected category and keeps the old ones ass well. Also I want the input field to be hidden initially and when I select a category that has subcategories to appear.

Comment: Idk how is your code, but you could initialize `second-dropdown` with `class: hidden`, and replace child elements instead of `append`, but that's weird because you already is cleaning it with `.html('')`..